# R shiny File Upload raster ASCII

Tags: r, import, ascii, raster, shiny

I would like to use the file upload controls `fileInput` in R shiny to import an ASCII file using `raster` from the raster Package, do some math with the imported raster layer and `plot` it in the end. When I try this, I get the following error:

> Error in .local(x, ...) : list has no "x"

Is there a way to get ASCII files imported as `raster` with the R shiny file upload controls?
As I don't know how to create a ASCII file within R, you can download one [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17914446/example.asc) to make the example reproducible.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(raster)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Header1"),

sidebarPanel(
fileInput('layer', 'Choose Layer', multiple=FALSE, accept='asc')
),

mainPanel(
plotOutput("mapPlot")
)
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(raster)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$mapPlot <- renderPlot({

inFile <- input$layer

if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

data <- raster(inFile)

plot(data)

})
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raster(inFile)` should be `raster(inFile$datapath)`.